# When is $u \circ v=v \circ u$ for $p$-adic power series $u$ and $v$ in two power series rings $A$ and $B$ respectively?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-rings, p-adic-numbers

Let $K \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field with ring of integers $O_K$ and maximal ideal $m_K$. Let $\bar K$ be the algebraic closure and $\bar{m}_K$ be the integral closure of $m_K$ with absolute Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$. Consider the ring of power series  $R:=x\mathcal{O}_K[[x]]$ (without constant terms).

**Construction:** We construct two subrings $A$ and $B$ of $R$ such that each elements of $A$ commutes with each other i.e., $f,g \in A \Rightarrow f \circ g= g \circ f.$ The same hold for $B$. Let $S \subset \bar{m}_K$ be an infinite subset of $\bar{m}_K$.

**Assumption:**

$(i)$ There exists a $\sigma_1(x) \in G$ and a series $u \in A$ such that $\sigma_1(x)=u(x)$ for all $x \in S$.

$(ii)$ There exists a $\sigma_2(x) \in G$ and a series $v \in A$ such that $\sigma_2(x)=v(x)$ for all $x \in S$.

**Question:**

When is $u \circ v=v \circ u$ ?

Or, when is  $\tilde{u} \circ \tilde{v}=\tilde{v} \circ \tilde{u}$ for an $\tilde{u} \in A$ and an $\tilde{v} \in B$

From the given assumptions, we have

\begin{align}
u(v(x))&=\sigma_1(\sigma_2(x)) \ \text{for all} \ x \in S \\
v(u(x))&=\sigma_2(\sigma_1(x)) \ \text{for all} \ x \in S.
\end{align}

If the absolute Galois group $G$ is abelian (big assumption) on $\bar{m}_K$, then we have $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(x))=\sigma_2(\sigma_1(x))$ and in that case we would have
$$u(v(x))=v(u(x)) \ \text{for all} \ x \in S, \ ----(1)$$

Now we note an important property that any power series in $R$ has **only finitely many** roots in $\bar{m}_K$ and hence in $S$.

Since $u\circ v-v \circ u$ vanishes on **infinite set** $S$, we must have $u\circ v-v \circ u\equiv 0$, that is, $u\circ v=v \circ u$. So we are done when the absolute Galois group $G$ is abelian on $\bar{m}_K$. But does it make sense that $G$ is abelian on $\bar{m}_K$ ? If it makes sense, does this conditions gives any information about the rings $A$ and $B$ ?

Can we assume that the roots of power series in either $A$ or in $B$ ensures $G$ to be abelian on $S \subset \bar{m}_K$ ?

> Is there any other way to answer my question ?

I want to impose some conditions on the subrings $A$ and $B$ so that my question is answered.

I appreciate any discussion.

Thanks

Comment: A more specific title would be welcome.

Comment: @YCor, Thanks. I have edited the title